# Inconsistent Django ORM Query Results With "Q" vs "__in"

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I'm trying to find all instances of one of my models that has an attribute set either to None or to an empty string. I think I'm missing something about the ORM's __in query.

```
TextBlock.objects.filter(content='').count()
>185
TextBlock.objects.filter(content=None).count()
>235
TextBlock.objects.filter(content__in=['', None]).count()
>185
TextBlock.objects.filter(Q(content='')|Q(content=None)).count()
>420
TextBlock.objects.filter(content__in=[None, '']).count()
>185
```

When I do this with an IntegerFIeld and not using None or empty strings, I get:

```
TextBlock.objects.filter(order=1).count()
> 575046
TextBlock.objects.filter(order=2).count()
> 11946
TextBlock.objects.filter(order__in=[1,2]).count()
> 586992
```

This is what I'd expect. Was I wrong to expect `TextBlock.objects.filter(content__in=['', None]).count()` to return 420 results? If so, why?

The Q query does what I want, so I'll end up going with that, but I'm still curious about why that third query didn't do what I wanted.

Thanks!

EDIT: Not sure if it makes a difference, but the content field is a models.TextField and the order field is a models.IntegerField

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `NULL == NULL` is actually false in SQL, and you need to use `IS NULL` to check if a value is null. Django is smart enough to convert `Q(content=None)` to an `IS NULL` statement, that's why `TextBlock.objects.filter(Q(content='')|Q(content=None)).count()` returns the results you'd expect.

An `IN` statement can only compare a value against its elements, it can't do an `IS NULL` check. To check against null values you need to explicitly add `content=None` or the equivalent `content__isnull=True`.

The query using `__in` should work as expected for any list of values that doesn't include `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

For checking if content is None you shouldn't use the comparison.
You have to use content__isnull in the ORM
(and you can combine queries with the Q object like you're doing)

Answer (score 0):

You check for `None` values using [`isnull`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#isnull) field lookup:

```
TextBlock.objects.filter(Q(content='')|Q(content__isnull=True)).count()
```